# How to get full value of a blob from sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite Administrator to query a blob in a table.  I'm using a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT quote(data) FROM versions WHERE id = '....'
```

The blob is longer than 256 characters.  When I look at the results, I'm only getting the first 256 characters back.

The blob contains XML.  How do I query the database so I get the full XML back?

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a quick WinForms application to retrieve the data from the database and put it into a `TextBox` control.  Thanks anyway.